# Why dictonary object to json to fill dropdown does not preserve order list

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to populate drowdown list in jquery from my controller method which return ordered dictionary object for key value pair. but when my drop down list filled, it does not preserve the order why is is like so

Here is my controller action method code ..

```
    public JsonResult GetRolesByGroupId(string groupCode)
    {
        var getRoleList = BusinessLayer.GetRoles()
            .Where(x => x.GroupCode == groupCode)
            .Select(i => new {i.RoleId, i.RoleDesc})
            .OrderBy(i => i.RoleDesc)
            .ToList();

        //var groupCodeList = getRoleList.Where(x => x.GroupCode == groupCode).OrderBy(o => o.RoleDesc)
         //   .ToDictionary(g => g.RoleId.ToString(), g => g.RoleDesc);

         Dictionary<string, string> objlist = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         getRoleList.ForEach(e=>objlist.Add(e.RoleId.ToString(),e.RoleDesc));

       
        return Json(objlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and here is my jquery code..

```
     $('#groupCodeList').on("change",
            function () {
                if ($('#groupCodeList option:selected').text() === "All") {
                    $('#RoleId').empty();
                    $('#RoleId').append('<option value=""></option>');
                    $('#RoleId').append('<option value="">All</option>');
                } else {
                    if ($('#groupCodeList option:selected').text()) {
                        $.getJSON(getRolesUrl,
                            { groupCode: $('#groupCodeList').val() },
                            function (data) {
                                $('#RoleId').empty();
                                $('#RoleId').append('<option value="">--Select--</option>');
                                $.each(data,
                                    function (key, val) {
                                        $('#RoleId').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + val + '</option>');
                                    });
                            });
                    } else {

                        $('#RoleId').empty();
                        $('#RoleId').append('<option value=""></option>');
                        //selectedCategory = "";
                    }

                }
```

What is the issue here, can someone help me, how to bind dropdown with sorted dictionary/list object with json in jquery.? help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to  fill dropdown and preserve order list, there are two ways, you can refer to them, hope them can help :

**One way:**

you can remove `Dictionary<string, string> objlist` , just return ordered `getRoleList` .

like:

```
 return Json(getRoleList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Then  change below:

```
$.each(data,
      function (key, val) {
      $('#RoleId').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + val + '</option>');
                                    });
```

with:

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
        $("#RoleId").append(`<option value="${item.roleId}">${item.roleDesc}</option>`);
                    });
```

**Second way:**

Exchange the  `Dictionary<string, string> objlist` key and value like:

```
 getRoleList.ForEach(e => objlist.Add(e.RoleDesc,e.RoleId.ToString()));
```

Then change the code like:

```
$.each(data,
  function (key, val) {
     $('#RoleId').append('<option value="' + val + '">' + key + '</option>');
                        });
```

Comment: Great, thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/17124525/qing-guo. both the options are working fine. I'll go with first since don't want to use dictionary here. it's my bad I have done it some time back but unfortunately didn't click back to my mind. anyway thanks a lot to remind me.